# Edit option is opened in every row when clicked

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, ecmascript-6

I am working on an application , where I've to show Edit Popup when click on icon . Now it working fine but problem is whenever I click on row it showing in each individual rows. I want to show single popup with each row not multiple . Now if I click on 5 rows popup showing 5 times I want to show single popup in each individual row

```
  const editToggle = (index) => {
    if (index === id) {
      setShowModal(true)
    }
  }

 {showModal && (
            <div className="card-container">
              <div className="container_separator card-container-text">Edit</div>
              <div className="container_separator card-container-text">Delete</div>
            </div>
          )}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `id` of the row you wish to open in the `showModal` state, and open the modal if the `showModal` value is identical to the `id`:

```
const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(-1)

const editToggle = (index) => {
  if (index === id) {
    setShowModal(id)
  }
}

{showModal === id && (
  <div className="card-container">
    <div className="container_separator card-container-text">Edit</div>
    <div className="container_separator card-container-text">Delete</div>
  </div>
)}
```